# Android Tabs (within tabs there should be scroll view) with collapse header

Tags: android, tabs, header, scrollview

Android tabs with collapse header, this header is below Action bar where screen will be present, so tabs will be almost center of the layout
So first i need header to be scrolled and then after reaching some height then the scroll view within the selected tab should scroll.
Please Download zip file from below link
http://www.filedropper.com/profilescreenimp2

Answer (score 0):

Make your `layout` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:text="Toolbar Title" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying can you help in implementing this feature little more in depth

Comment: @Logic, I think he wants a collapsing header. Need a CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Comment: @user3614958, coordinator layout hides toolbar if user swipes upwards

Comment: Hi Friends i have shared a link, where you can download that zip file and check.The shared code working well for list view but failed to work on scrollview

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/homeCoordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeAppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeCollapseToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            //This can be changed to ImageView
            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/homeSliderLayout"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
                android:title=""
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="115dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/homeTabLayout"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/homeViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```